# Array increasing the values [python]

Tags: python, arrays, addition

I have an array

```
a = [4, 5, 6]

for x in a:
x=x + 1

print(a)
```

It doesn't change the array. I want 5 6 7

Comment: `s = set(thing.keys())`

Comment: @ThuYeinTun you just need `set(thing)`, actually

Comment: `del values` *removes the name `values` from the current namespace*. `del` **never deletes objects**. In any case, `values` is essentially a set-like view over the values in a dictionary, and deleting that object would have no effect on the dictionary object.

Comment: And more fundamentally, a dict isn't just a set with values... you can't just "delete the values" and magically create a set object. Python never works like this. You can't just change the type of an object like that, especially not built-in types (without crazy introspection hijinks and hackery).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the comment. I do have one question. If `del` never deletes objects, then how do python prevent memory leaks? If the object reference from current namespace is gone, the reference counter should be decreased or zeroed right?

Comment: @ThuYeinTun yes. The using `del` *can* result in an object being garbage collected, but that isn't what it is doing directly. It merely removes a name from a namespace. Generally, you almost never use `del`, aside from a few cases. It generally isn't required to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] Try this:

```
s = set(thing)
```

Comment: That’s `set(thing)`.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
>>> keys = thing.keys()
>>> print(keys)
['wak', 'holng']
```